# Bootstrap Carousel Not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the Twitter Bootstrap carousel, and so far I've been unsuccessful. I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fluxware: Play, learn and build games</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Home page for Fluxware">
  <meta name="author" content="Tim Butram">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
  <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--For shitty webbrowsers -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/sbn/trunk/html5.js></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="favicon" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Build</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Grid -->
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="span12">
      <div class="hero-unit">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img src="/images/1.png" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="./images/2.png" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="./images/3.png" /></div>
          </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
           <a class="btn btn-large">Play</a>
       <p>Play games created with Fluxware.</p>

        </div>

    <div class="span4">
      <a class="btn btn-large">Learn</a>
      <p>Learn how to create games and game assets</p>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
          <a class="btn btn-large">Build</a>

      <p>Use the Fluxware tools to create game.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

  <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And everything seems to render correctly, except for the carousel. From reading the Bootstrap page, it appears that I need to stick a

```
$('.myCarousel').carousel();
```

somewhere, but I have no clue as to where, how or why. In addition to that, in the Firefox error console, I get the two errors

```
$ is undefined
```

in bootstrap-carousel.js [line 125] and

```
$ is not a function
```

in bootstrap-transition.js [line 22]

Comment: From what I understand, $('.carousel').carousel(); is jQuery to call the carousel method on the DIV with id = carousel. So, I put that in a script at the bottom. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to do anything, except for creating another error of '$ is not defined'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly jQuery wasn't loaded correctly.
Try loading the two scripts in the page `<head>`.

The code to run the carousel is

```
<script>
// Load this when the DOM is ready
$(function(){
  // You used .myCarousel here. 
  // That's the class selector not the id selector,
  // which is #myCarousel
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```

You can put it either in the `<head>` after the two other scripts
or where the other scripts are now.

Comment: Ugh. You're correct that jQuery was not loading correctly. It wasn't even there.

Thanks for the help with my js snippet placement.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.

- For me i had to use jQuery 1.7.1 , as 1.6.4 didn't work.
- i had to include [bootstrap-transition](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js)

Answer (score 3):

Recently had the same problem, it seems in the current version of Bootstrap, you must also include a class called slide.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide span12">
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined as id not a class , So you should start carousel by this code of jquery , so replace

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

instead of

```
$('.myCarousel').carousel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Django's JQuery` (I don't know the version) and it was not working.
However, it works with `Jquery 1.7.1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling getting a Bootstrap carousel slideshow to work -- 
Here's a template with positionable controls, and a progress navbar at the bottom that tracks the slides.

[http://codepen.io/TheNickelDime/][1]

```
<div class="Slideshow_carousel-wrapper container-fluid">
    <span class="Slideshow-ctl-L" onclick="carousel_left()"></span>
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  ... </div>    
    <span class="Slideshow-ctl-R" onclick="carousel_right()"></span>

</div>

   <div class="container-fluid Slideshow_progress-bar">     
        <ul id="slideshow_progress" class="Slideshow_progress"></ul>
    </div>
```