# Adding Twitter Bootstrap Carousel to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I just started ruby on rails a few weeks ago, I'm currently building a blog using rails composer ( which uses twitter-bootstrap-rails gem ). I want to add the bootstrap carousel to my application view ( ie to my application.html.erb)

I already tried to add the classic html code from the twitter bootstrap documentation but I just get the right and left controller buttons with no pictures displayed.

Does somebody have the solution for me ?

PS : I currently use Sass for my bootstrap design.

EDIT 02-11-2013 => Here's my code hope you can find what my mistake is

```
<div class="container">
    <!--  Carousel -->
  <!--  consult Bootstrap docs at
        http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel -->
  <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item">
          <a><img src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Antennae Galaxies" /></a>

        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p>The Antennae Galaxies</p>
          <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2006046a/xlarge_web/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <a><img src="assets/images/2.jpg" alt="Carina Caterpillar" /></a>

        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p>Carina Nebula: The Caterpillar</p>
          <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2007016e/xlarge_web/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
    <!--  next and previous controls here
          href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div><!-- .carousel -->
  <!-- end carousel -->
    <div class="content">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div> <!--! end of .container -->
</div> <!--! end of #main -->

<script>
$(function(){
$('#this-carousel-id').carousel();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2 : And this is how it looks like on Chrome : http://s7.postimage.org/kvp5cq4tn/Capture_d_cran_11_02_13_18_46_2.png

Comment: Do you have code you can show us? It's kind of difficult for us to just guess.

Comment: Double check that your images are located in your assets/images folder and that you are calling them using the correct path.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
img src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Antennae Galaxies",
```

Use the following image tag for rails:

```
link_to image_tag("1.jpg", :alt => "Slide1"), {:class => "img-responsive", :alt => "Responsive image"}
```

and there is no need to specify "assets/images" for showing the image folder. the `1.jpg` is enough!

Answer (score 1):

Does your app/assets/javascripts/application.js contain a reference to bootstrap?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

My carousel as a reference:

```
                <div class="span8 welcome-image">


                        <div id="myCarousel"
                        class="carousel slide">
                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="active item">
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up"><img src="/pictures/1.png"> </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up"><img src="/pictures/2.png"> </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up"><img src="/pictures/3.png"> </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up"><img src="/pictures/4.png"> </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up"><img src="/pictures/WordcloudInsight.png"> </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Yes my app/assets/javascripts/application.js looks exactly like that. I will give a try and add <script>
$(function(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script> to my application view !

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap Carousel in Rails suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812946/bootstrap-carousel-in-rails-suddenly-stopped-working)

check above link, also did you add this + is jquery loading

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```