# Bootstrap Carousel Transitions and Prev/Next Buttons Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel

I'm trying to implement the twitter bootstrap carousel, and it's not working - it doesn't switch images automatically, AND the previous/next buttons don't work.

I've tried switching to jquery 1.7.1 as suggested on [Bootstrap Carousel Not Automatically Sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233449/bootstrap-carousel-not-automatically-sliding) and [Bootstrap Carousel Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353294/bootstrap-carousel-not-working), but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slideshow Test</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:450px">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active"><img src="img/IMG_2.jpg"></div>                
                <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_3.jpg"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_1.jpg"></div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

You can view it and its linked files at [www.abbymilberg.com/bootstrap](http://www.abbymilberg.com/bootstrap).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303146/3585056
This has fixed my problem.
Give ID to parent container

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should include bootstrap.js after you include jquery.js:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, **bootstrap-transition.js** should come prior to all other Bootstrap plugins (but still after jQuery, as Daniil correctly identified).

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, even including .js in the propper order, and I fixed it unsing javascript on 'onclick' event as follows:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" onclick="$('#myCarousel').carousel('prev')">‹</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" onclick="$('#myCarousel').carousel('next')">›</a>
```

I know that it's not the cleanest solution but it works.

Comment: If you have this issue, make sure the href in the prev/next buttons refers to the correct ID.  It should be #id (jquery notation).  Should be no need to add onclick.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm going for the `onclick` dirty fix but if you happen to know why it did not work I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: You could also add return false like this  onclick="$('#carouselInner').carousel('next'); return false;"

Comment: Same here on bs4

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="left carousel-control" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"/>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</div>
<div class="right carousel-control" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"/>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do a class to your button and put data-target  check on my code  thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding z-index to the css:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This helped me since I was using a hack to change the ``.carousel-caption``'s z-index, so I had to also change the z-index of the controls so they appeared on top of the caption.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms, but my problem was that I didn't included an id to my carousel. Adding an id on the same div that has the `.carousel` class, and using `href="#my-carousel"` on the button/links solved the problem for me, as suggested by other users in the comments.

```html
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:450px">
            ^----------------------------------v
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#my-carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#my-carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try closing "carousel-inner" before the controls start

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:450px">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img src="img/IMG_2.jpg"></div>                
        <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: This is because OP includes jquery after bootstrap. This will not help

Comment: Well it worked for these guys http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Comment: This is because bootstrap trying to use jQuery before jQuery is avaible for use.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Just really thought it was that div though.

Comment: Putting jquery before bootstrap fixed my original problem, but after I did that it still wasn't looping correctly after going through all of my slides. Following this suggestion fixed that problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `data-slide` to `data-bs-slide`. This worked for me.

Comment: This working as well.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer by `user2139170`, this is the correct way to structure your carousel (BootStrap 3.3.5):

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yv80533m/)</kbd>

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <h4>A mind-bending lecture on applied philosophy by Oxford lecturer Ravi Zacharias.</h4>
            <br>
            <span class="font-normal">youtube/watch?v=3ZZaoavCsYE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>Director of the Human Genome Project discusses the greatest mystery of life</h4>
            <br>
            <span class="font-normal">youtube/watch?v=EGu_VtbpWhE</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div><!-- #myCarousel -->

<script>
    $(function(){

        $('.carousel-control').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myCarousel').carousel( $(this).data() );
        });

    });//END document.ready
</script>
```

---

*Note: this answer requires jQuery, so ensure that library is loaded. Of course, bootstrap requires jQuery so you should already have it referenced.*

Answer (score 0):

> Using the below code will help you out

**the buttons function well**

*Run the code snippet to check whether it solves your problem or not*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(2).jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(4).jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(6).jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Prev/Next buttons were not working. It was because of old versions of the bootstrap js scripts.

I used the latest recommended version of javascripts (both jquery and bootstrap) mentioned in bootstrap website and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've pasted the correct bootstrap links in the head tag. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: try changing to different versions of bootstrap. bootstrap version 5.1x was giving me some problems so i changed it to 4.6 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

simple replace this code with

```html
   <a class="carousel-control left" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

then it will work.

the problem is href replacing it with data-target will work.

Answer (score 0):

Loading bootstrap.js before JQuery-1.7.1.min.js creates this problem, ensure JQuery is loaded before bootstrap.js