# Bootstrap Carousel example template not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to incorporate the Carousel example template into my project: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

This is my HTML. The CSS and JS files load fine. To give you a good idea of what exactly is missing, here is my page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJmMr.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
<body>
# The body was directly copy-pasted, except that the bootstrap.js and jquery.js 
# files were moved to the top of the page from the bottom for debug convenience
</body>
```

Edit: I forgot that you have to initialize it with $('.carousel').carousel();. I added that just before the carousal HTML, but it still does not work.

Comment: I found the answer - turns out the carousel won't work until you add images to it. Adding images from my own static files solved the 'problem'.

Answer (score 0):

[Answered in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353553/1162711)

I will quote it here as I think this might be your problem.

---

Clearly jQuery wasn't loaded correctly.
Try loading the two scripts in the page .

The code to run the carousel is

```
<script>
  // Load this when the DOM is ready
$(function(){
  // You used .myCarousel here. 
  // That's the class selector not the id selector,
  // which is #myCarousel
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```

You can put it either in the  after the two other scripts
or where the other scripts are now.